how can i send audio chunk from backend node via socket to react js and listen to it in realtime as chunk of audio is being generated
I am sending audio chunk via socket connection to my react client.
  for await (let chunk of audioStream) {
    if (chunk) {
    
      socket.emit("audioChunk", chunk);
      
    }
  }

im getting the audio chunk in frontend. Now i want to play the chunks im getting continuously. how can i do this. i need help. thanks
How do I efficiently buffer the incoming audio chunks in real-time? How can I play the audio chunks continuously, without interruptions or glitches, as they are received?
